# GridView to CSV with re-ordered columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, gridview

I have a GridView with automatically generated columns from an EAV source. By default the columns are in alphabetical order but they can be rearranged with some jQuery magic. The data needs to be output in a CSV using the column order the user has defined.

jQuery magic thing I'm using: https://github.com/akottr/dragtable
(I could be convinced to use a different method for rearranging the columns if the solution requires)

CSV output is as follows:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < grdResults.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++){
    sb.Append(grdView.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text.Replace(',', ';') + ',');
}
//append new line
sb.Append("\r\n");
for (int i = 0; i < grdView.Rows.Count; i++){
   for (int j = 0; j < grdView.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++){
     sb.Append(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Rows[i].Cells[j].Text.Replace(',', ';'))+ ',');
   }
   sb.Append("\r\n");
}

FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                               FileAccess.ReadWrite);
fs.Close();
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FileName, false, 
                                    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
sw.Write(sb.ToString());
sw.Close();

if (sb.Length > 0)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                    string.Format("attachment;filename=Report{0}.csv",
                    DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss")));
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length",
                      Convert.ToString(sb.ToString().Length));
    Response.ContentType = "text/HTML";
    Response.WriteFile(FileName);
    Response.End();
}
```

I did it this way because the cent symbol comes out funny in excel if it is ANSI or different UTF and this allowed me to control the encoding.

The columns are always in the default order. How can I output a CSV with the re-ordered column order?

-A solution could use javascript/jQuery, or server side with the C# back-end and can require re-working existing components.

-An acceptable solution must also allow for the the cent symbol to be correctly displayed in excel after exporting.

**UPDATE:** Thanks for the help, I got it mostly working. However the cent symbol `¢` is coming out as `Â¢`; so `79¢` is `79Â¢`.  If I open it in notepad or notepad++ it is correct.

String.charCodeAt() has it as a 162. So `41¢` is `52, 49, 162`.

-Why is excel adding an extra character?

-Is there a different charcode I could do a replace so it shows up properly in excel?

**UPDATE2:** When a wild `¢` appears I just convert it to dollars and use a `$` instead.  This seems like a satisfactory solution for the manager.

Comment: You can use jquery datatables. It has rich api and come up with export to excel CSV word out of The box and its free

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/KPEGU/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with naveen's solution: http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/KPEGU   I had to tweek it a little to fit my specific case but it works well.

I changed line from:

```
$cols = $row.find('td')
```

to:

```
$cols = $row.find('th,td');
```

So I could get the table headers as well, and added a special case to handle that pesky `¢`.

I'm just going to mark this as the answer because it was answered in the comments, and anyone browsing will see a green box showing and can come look for the solution.

**If anyone has a solution that can keep a `¢` in the excel output I would mark that as the answer.**